# How i can implement a IsKeyPressed function in a delphi console application?

Tags: delphi

I have a delphi console application which i need terminate when the user press any key, the problem is which i don't know how implement a function to detect when a key is pressed , i want to do something like so.

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

begin
 MyTask:=MyTask.Create;
 try
 MyTask.RunIt; 
  while MyTask.Running and not IsKeyPressed do //how i can implement a IsKeyPressed  function?
    MyTask.SendSignal($56100AA);
 finally
   MyTask.Stop;
   MyTask.Free;
 end;
```

end.

Comment: are you sure you want a busy loop? Why not break on ctrl+break?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can write a function to detect if a key was pressed checking the [`console input buffer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682079%28VS.85%29.aspx).

> Each console has an input buffer that
>   contains a queue of input event
>   records. When a console's window has
>   the keyboard focus, a console formats
>   each input event (such as a single
>   keystroke, a movement of the mouse, or
>   a mouse-button click) as an input
>   record that it places in the console's
>   input buffer.

First you must call the [GetNumberOfConsoleInputEvents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683207%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to get the number of events, then retrieve the event using the [PeekConsoleInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684344%28VS.85%29.aspx) function and check if the event is a `KEY_EVENT` finally flush the console input buffer using [FlushConsoleInputBuffer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683147%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Check this sample

```
function KeyPressed:Boolean;
var
  lpNumberOfEvents     : DWORD;
  lpBuffer             : TInputRecord;
  lpNumberOfEventsRead : DWORD;
  nStdHandle           : THandle;
begin
  Result:=false;
  //get the console handle
  nStdHandle := GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
  lpNumberOfEvents:=0;
  //get the number of events
  GetNumberOfConsoleInputEvents(nStdHandle,lpNumberOfEvents);
  if lpNumberOfEvents<> 0 then
  begin
    //retrieve the event
    PeekConsoleInput(nStdHandle,lpBuffer,1,lpNumberOfEventsRead);
    if lpNumberOfEventsRead <> 0 then
    begin
      if lpBuffer.EventType = KEY_EVENT then //is a Keyboard event?
      begin
        if lpBuffer.Event.KeyEvent.bKeyDown then //the key was pressed?
          Result:=true
        else
          FlushConsoleInputBuffer(nStdHandle); //flush the buffer
      end
      else
      FlushConsoleInputBuffer(nStdHandle);//flush the buffer
    end;
  end;
end;
```