# Console: abort Read or Readln

Tags: delphi, console-application

The console `Read` command does not recognize `VK_ESCAPE`. When using `ReadConsoleInput`, it is case insensitive. Is there something adequate to `Read`/`Readln`, which reports an abort?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/16023313/576719.

Comment: VK_ESCAPCE? ATypo?

Comment: @Dsm see unit `Winapi.Windows.VK_ESCAPE`

Comment: @USauter: Which is indeed very different from your original `VK_ESCAPCE`!

Answer (score 2):

- [The docs on `Read()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.Read) tell you it's for characters, not keys in general. It will also not help you to i.e. recognize <kbd>PgUp</kbd> or <kbd>Print</kbd>. That's also why it is so similar to [`Readln()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.Readln), which unsurprisingly is for text, too, not separate keys being pressed.
- A console process does not know by default what "abort" means. Common knowledge (even unbound to *Windows*) is that [<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and/or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Break</kbd> terminate the process](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Console_Applications#How_your_console_application_terminates).
- Neither a [`ReadConsoleInput()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/readconsoleinput) nor is its [KEY_EVENT record](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/key-event-record-str) case insensitive: again you get keys, not characters. Which means you have to check if `.dwControlKeyState` has either `SHIFT_PRESSED` or `CAPSLOCK_ON` set to translate all the keys into an appropriate character (i.e. only <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> makes it an uppercase S).

It's up to you to decide when to interpret keys and when treating input as text/characters. Yes: recognizing <kbd>Esc</kbd> while using `Readln()` will never work - you'd have to reinvent your own `Readln()`, i.e. dealing with all the input, including your favorite keys, such as <kbd>Esc</kbd>. This will also help you discover which keys (that you type) lead to which VK constants.