# RestClient and thread locking

Tags: multithreading, delphi

Using Delphi 10.4

Using the tool REST Debugger, called an API, And got compoents.

Calling the Componets with

```
begin
  writeln('starting');
    RESTRequest1.Execute; writeln('finieshed 1');
    RESTRequest2.Execute; writeln('finieshed 2');
    RESTRequest3.Execute; writeln('finieshed 3');
  writeln('Done.');

end;
```

when i debug the code

and in the Execute there is a line

```
  // Eventhandlers AFTER Observers
  HandleEvent(DoAfterExecute);
```

which leads to the procedure:

```
class procedure TThread.Synchronize(const AThread: TThread; AMethod: TThreadMethod);
var
  LSynchronize: TSynchronizeRecord;
begin
  LSynchronize.Init(AThread, AMethod);
  Synchronize(@LSynchronize); // <--- here
end;
```

and the code locks.

I think its a dead lock, however I don't know what is locked.

the setup is a Thread in console application.

```
Download := TDownload.Create(nil);
// Simulate service start.
Download.ServiceStart(Download, MyDummyBoolean);
readln;
// On exit, destroy the service object.
FreeAndNil(DownloadInvoices);
```

The Documentation of RestClient is lacking.
What it is locked?
or How to identify the locking procedure?

Comment: inspecting the AEventHandler shows "(no value)" which means someone forgot to check nil on the condition of HandleEvent in Rest.Client?

Comment: using this website: https://www.delphipower.xyz/learning/the_go_to_address_command.html i found the proceudre with the code address in the debugging tool : DoAfterExecute

Comment: this answer hints that the readln is blocking TThread.Synchronize() https://stackoverflow.com/a/16023313/418198

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is with the `Synchronize` call in the RTL.

`Synchronize` is picked up in the main message loop when the application is idle (i.e. it has no events to process).

As you have said this is a console application I suspect you do not have a main message loop that can register that the application is idle, or process the waiting `Synchronize` calls.

There's no way around that if you want to use components that call `Syncronize` - you must have an appropriate message loop.  The easiest way is to implement a simple VCL, FMX or Service application and the `Synchronize` calls will succeed.

As an alternative you can write your own main loop. As per Remy Lebeau's comments below you need to call `CheckSynchronize()` periodically, and you can make use of the RTL's `SyncEvent` to know when to call `CheckSynchronize()`. The documentation also mentions using the global variable `WakeMainThread` to store an object method (`TNotifyEvent`) that is called when the worker thread has obtained the lock on the main thread.

The edit is not allowing me to add links for some reason.
For `CheckSynchronize` see: https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.CheckSynchronize

For `SyncEvent` see: https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.SyncEvent

Comment: "*There's no way around that if you want to use components that call Syncronize - you must have an appropriate message loop.*" - that is not true. You just need to have the main thread (or even another worker thread) call [`CheckSynchronize()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.CheckSynchronize) periodically. There is even a [`SyncEvent`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.SyncEvent) you can wait on to know when to call `CheckSynchronize()`.

Comment: Thanks @RemyLebeau - I did say *"I suspect you do not have a main message loop that can register that the application is idle, or process the waiting `Synchronize` calls."*  I appreciate that the next sentence, which you have quoted, starts a new paragraph.  I will update my answer to incorporate your useful comments.

Comment: Calling the CheckSynchronize() on the main thread Solved it. i needed to iterate in the main thread, so i changed this answer code to return if its key press or timeout. and keep the loop as long as there is no keypress https://stackoverflow.com/a/29378307/418198 THANK YOU