# Delphi - How can I ask for user input while other segments of the code are running

Tags: delphi

The game i'm trying to make is snake, in the console application. I can get the snake to move along the screen however I am not sure how I can read the user inputing the keys WASD, code segment shown below.

```
write (StoredTrail); //This would be writing the snake, each segment is '[]'
repeat
clearScreen; // This is calling a clear screen procedure, if there is a simple way to make the snake disappear from the console that avoids such a lengthy procedure that would be great to know.
delete (StoredTrail ,0,2); 
StoredTrail:= A+StoredTrail; //This makes the trail move along(A is '  ')
write(StoredTrail);
Xcord:= Xcord + 1;
sleep(150);
until 1=2;
```

I am also aware the sleep is very inefficient so if anyone had a better way to delay the movement of the snake that would also be welcomed. Coding for increasing the snakes length is also not implemented yet.

Many thanks to anyone able to help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How i can implement a IsKeyPressed function in a delphi console application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5845080/how-i-can-implement-a-iskeypressed-function-in-a-delphi-console-application)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the days of Turbo Pascal an ancient predecessor of Delphi there was a CRT unit that provided some useful functions for console applications. Two such functions that would be of interest to you for keyboard input are `KeyPressed()` which returns true if a key has been pressed and `GetKey()` which returns the key pressed. For Delphi itself there are a few sources of libraries that offer compatible functions. One is Rudy's [Velthuis.Console unit](http://rvelthuis.de/programs/console.html).

Answer (score 3):

I give an example for a event driven console application, which update the screen iterativelly.
It would be too long to write here the user event handler routines and you can find it on a lot of places on the net. [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/reading-input-buffer-events) is a fine example, which handle keyboard and mouse events as well:

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
    System.SysUtils
  , Vcl.ExtCtrls
  ;

type
  TSnakeApp = class
    private
      fTimer : TTimer;
      fExit : boolean;
    protected
      function createTimer : TTimer; virtual;
      procedure releaseTimer; virtual;
      procedure drawSnake( timer_ : TObject ); virtual;
      procedure handleKeyBoardEvents; virtual;

    public
      constructor create;
      destructor destroy; override;
      procedure run;
  end;

var
 app : TSnakeApp;

function TSnakeApp.createTimer : TTimer;
begin
  result := TTimer.Create( NIL );
end;

procedure TSnakeApp.releaseTimer;
begin
  fTimer.Free;
end;

procedure TSnakeApp.drawSnake( timer_ : TObject );
begin
  // if it takes too long time (>= times.interval), then disable+enable the timer
  fTimer.enabled := FALSE;
  try
  finally
    fTimer.enabled := TRUE;
  end;
end;

procedure TSnakeApp.handleKeyBoardEvents;
begin
  // It would be too long to write here, but you can find a very nice keyboard/mouse event handler for console applications here:
  // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/reading-input-buffer-events
  //  case ( keyPressed ) of
  //    VK_ESC:
  //      fExit := TRUE;
  //  ...
end;

constructor TSnakeApp.create;
begin
  inherited create;
  fTimer := createTimer;
  fTimer.Interval := 20;
  fTimer.OnTimer := drawSnake;
end;

destructor TSnakeApp.destroy;
begin
  releaseTimer;
  inherited destroy;
end;

procedure TSnakeApp.run;
begin
  fTimer.enabled := TRUE;
  while ( not fExit ) do
  begin
    handleKeyBoardEvents;
  end;
  fTimer.enabled := FALSE;
end;

begin
  try
    try
      app := TSnakeApp.create;
      app.run;
    finally
      app.Free;
    end;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```